# Error: Unknown column 'joinedactivities.searchact id = searchact.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I keep getting this error Error: Unknown column 'joinedactivities.searchact id = searchact.id' in 'on clause'. I have checked table names and tried changing it but I keep getting errors.

I have tables:

joinedactivities- id, user id(foreign key), searchact id(foreign key)

searchact-id,postcode, lat, long, hobby, venue

I am trying to display rows from table searchact from the foreign key searchact id.

```
$user=$_SESSION['id'];

$sql ="SELECT * FROM `joinedactivities` JOIN `searchact` ON `joinedactivities.searchact id = searchact.id` WHERE `user id`=$user "; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// output data of each row
  echo "Hobby : " . $row["searchact id"];
}
 } else {
echo "You have not joined any groups";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right but a slight mistake - Wrong backtracks. Use the code below

```
$user=$_SESSION['id'];

$sql ="SELECT * FROM `joinedactivities` JOIN `searchact` ON `joinedactivities`.`searchact id` = `searchact`.`id` WHERE `user id`=$user "; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
// output data of each row
  echo "Hobby : " . $row["searchact id"];
}
 } else {
echo "You have not joined any groups";
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Why did you add an underscore to the column `searchact id`?

Comment: Just made a slight mistake correcting it, thanks +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Backticks enclose database objects.  So you're telling the query engine that this entire thing is a single object (in this case a column):

```
`joinedactivities.searchact id = searchact.id`
```

I don't think you have a column named `joinedactivities.searchact id = searchact.id`, so the query is failing.  (And even if you did have a column named that, it would still be an incomplete `ON` clause.)  Enclose *individual* database objects in backticks:

```
`joinedactivities`.`searchact id` = `searchact`.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your backticks are incorrect:

```
`joinedactivities.searchact id = searchact.id` 
^--------------------------------------------^
```

You've turned that entire string into a single identifier. You probably want something more like

```
`joinedactivities`.`searchact_id` = `searchact`.`id`
```

And note that NONE of those identifiers are reserved words, which means that the backticks are not necessary at all.

Comment: It looks like the `searchact id` may genuinely have a space in it (you changed it to an underscore), which would then require backticks.  (Note also the `user id` column later in the query.)